# Getting GPS position in custom dialog

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm trying to getting location manager inside text-view in customDialog as follows:

But gives me java null pointer exception

When I open Dialog and get GPS working it works fine, but when closing Dialog and GPS get it's positions it getting NPE.

Note: I have edited the code for you

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tjamo3_last_date);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        addNewPoint.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Tjamo3LastDate.this);

                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                        dialog.setTitle("اضافة نقطة فحص جديدة");

                        Button save =(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.save);
                        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                            txtLat = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            txtLag = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                            txtLat.setText("0.0");
                            txtLag.setText("0.0");
                        }
                        dialog.show();
                        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                EditText editText=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                                txtLat = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                txtLag = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                                txtLat.setText(String.valueOf(mm));
                                txtLag.setText(String.valueOf(hh));

    });

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        hh = location.getLatitude();
        mm = location.getLongitude();
    }
```

Comment: Have you given the permissions ? In your Internet On ? are you checking this code in real device under open sky ?

Comment: this code is working fine , but i want to pass location.getLatitude(); to my textView in coustomDailog txtLat .

Comment: when i used txtLat.setText(location.getLatitude().toString()) gets NPE

Comment: ok got it. can you provide more code ? Activity file's code as well.

Comment: ok, give me few mins, Let me study the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48639/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-user3245658)

Comment: 1st add a if (location != null) { } and surround all your onLocationChanged

Comment: Am not sure if the onLocationChanged will get called if you have a dialog open. probably it will. But you try to get the coordinates when you click save. If the hh and mm are null(No location was received) then youll get an exception. Also surround your onClick with if hh and mm are not null then set the coords. But my only concern is whether the onLocationChanged is getting called. Try debug it a check the flow of the code

Answer (score 0):

As per our chat:

Keep a reference to txtLat and txtLang and in your dialog put this

```
if(location!=null){ 
   txtLat.setText("" + location.getLatitude()); 
   txtLag.setText("" + location.getLongitude()); 
}
```

Then replace onLocationChanged with this

```
@Override 
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) { 
   location = loc; 
   if(txtLat !=null && txtLag!=null){ 
   txtLat.setText("" + location.getLatitude()); 
   txtLag.setText("" + location.getLongitude()); 
}
```